# Chrome - Access variables from a webpage through my console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

If I have a page, that defines a set of JavaScript variables, for example:

```
const pageId = 1
const pageName = "pName"
```

Is it possible for me to access the variable by typing in the console window.

I know I can add code to the page to make the page output the variables eg:

```
console.log(pageId)
```

Will output 1 to to the console window, but this is not what I am asking.

I want to run the page with the code as it is, and then type into the `Chrome` developer tools, console tab, to get it to display the value of whatever variable I choose.

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: Is typing the code in your console not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Console runs in the same scope as the JS engine is currently operating in, so assuming they are global constants: Just access them as normal (by typing their name).

If they are not global, you can only access them if you move to within the right scope (e.g. with a breakpoint inside the same function).